# Extension update server "priority" attribute

Tags: joomla-3.x, extension-update, manifest

When deploying an update server for a basic extension, I'll normally use the following:

```
<updateservers>
    <server type="extension" name="Something" priority="1">http://example.com/update.xml</server>
</updateservers>
```

However I'm unsure as to what the `priority` attribute is for. I looked on the Joomla Docs and the description says:

> The priority of the update server

which I find extremely vague.

Can anyone shed some light as to how it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have multiple update servers, you can set a different priority for each. so you can control the order in which the update servers are checked.

If the first one is available, it won't bother checking the rest

Reference Book - [Learning Joomla! 3 Extension Development](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/learning-joomla-3-extension-development-third-edition)

Comment: Ah got it. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome :) sometimes books are useful :D